# How can I detect whether a method has changed since it was last compiled?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a requirement where i want to check if my method body is changed on run time. This is specifically for the test case using unit. I have steps in the test which i want to save in the database. But most of the time this steps will not change, hence don't want to overload my database by saving this step into the database every time it runs. I only want to save the new steps if new steps are added or modified.

e.g.

```
[Test]
 public void Should_Pass_When_SomethingHappened()
      {
        File.Open(TestFile);      //step 1
        File.Close()   //step2 
     }
```

Now if someone change this method to say below

```
[Test]
 public void Should_Pass_When_SomethingHappened()
      {
        File.Open(TestFile); //step1 
        File.Copy(Source, Desitnation); //step2      
        File.Close(); //step 3
     }
```

I want to capture this change in the test while running the test. This way, I can mark in a database that this test case has changed and avoid adding new steps in the database while keeping the original steps.

I tried this:

```
public int CheckIfMethodIfModified()
{
   Type TestType = typeof(MyTypeName);
   MethodInfo myMethodInfo = 
   TestType.GetMethod("Should_Pass_When_SomethingHappened");
   MethodBody mb = myMethodInfo.GetMethodBody();
   string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mb.GetILAsByteArray());
   result.GetHashCode();
}
```

This hashcode is not changing, even if my method is changed.

Comment: So your question isn't how to detect whether a method is changed at runtime. You want to debug your code that calculates a hash of a method's body. That's different. If you want help debugging your code, show your actual code, the input, the expected output and what you've tried to resolve those differences. Read [ask].

Comment: It works for me. Different code leads to different hashes. However, you shouldn't rely on `GetHashCode`, because it can return different results from version to version or in different environments. You may just generate hash from this byte array to make sure that you are dependent on `GetHashCode` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetHashCode` is specifically documented as not being reliable as a hashing method across different executions of an application.  It is *only* designed to be used as a key in a hash based data structure during a single execution of a single application, and nothing else.

If you want to create a hash that stays consistent across executions of an application then you'll need to use a different method.  For example, there are various cryptographic hashes that you can use that will consistently produce the same hash given the same input.

Comment: Can you please provide any library/package to produce consistent hashcode?